# Python3: re.match a command from a list of comands on a single line seperated by a ;

Tags: python-3.x, regex, match

I am trying to parse a command line, with 0 or more commands before of after a command.

The `<name>` is part of the line as well.

Example:

```py
cmd = 'lsg <name>; cd <name>;find . -type f -exec grep -i <name> {} \; -print;lsg ; ps axwwl ' 
pattern = r'.*(find.*-exec.*\\;?.*?;?)(;*.*$)' 
match = re.match(pattern, cmd)
```

What I am getting is:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -i <name> {} \;
```

What I am trying to do is just match the `find` command, i.e.:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -i <name> {} \; -print
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
match = re.search(r'\bfind\s.*-exec\s.*\\;?[^;]*', cmd)
if match:
    print(match.group())
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3L3dU2/3/). *Details*:

- `\bfind` - a `find` word that has no letter/digit/`_` right before it, and then
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `-exec` - an `-exec` string
- `\s.*` - a whitespace and then zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\\` - a `\` char
- `;?` - an optional `;` char
- `[^;]*` - zero or more chars other than `;`.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3ykVm7):

```py
import re
rx = r"\bfind\s.*-exec\s.*\\;?[^;]*"
text = r"lsg <name>; cd <name>;find . -type f -exec grep -i <name> {} \; -print;lsg ; ps axwwl "
match = re.search(rx, text)
if match:
    print (match.group())

# => find . -type f -exec grep -i <name> {} \; -print
```

Comment: Done, thanks again. I made a minor modification to your solution:

```
rx = r"(.*)(\bfind\s.*-exec\s.*\\;?[^;]*)(.*)"
```
That way I can retrieve what is before  and after with:

```
match.group[1]
match.group[2]
match.group[3]
```

Comment: @cmora111 That part was not that clear to me. Please pay attention that you need `.*?` instead of `.*` at the beginning if you plan to match the *first* `find` word in the string, and  you need to use your `.*` if you need to get to the last `find` (that will be part of the second group.

Comment: No problem. I was just looking for how to get whole find command. Since find uses a ':' to delimit the end of an '-exec' and the command seperator is a ';'. Thanks again.